# What are the possible basis for a four dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find remaining vectors of the basis of 4Dvector space If let two of them are given 
For ex - (0,0,0,1) and (0,0,1,1) are two vectors of basis of 4d VS.Find the other two.

Comment: "Find the other two" is an ambiguous request. There are infinitely many possible answers. Hint for one valid answer: can you make use of any of the elements of the standard basis for $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: Just pick 2 linearly independend vectors that are also linearly independend to your 2 already given vectors such as $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0)$ However, there is not just one possible basis of a 4 dimensional vector space.

Comment: Thanks guys.i got it.i just need to make a set of 4 LI vectors